# Bash vs. Gnu screen : Replace Ctrl-A with Ctrl-Shift-A

Tags: bash, gnu-screen, readline

I'm a new user to GNU Screen. I've been using Bash for a very long time, and I want to give GNU Screen a try.

As you know, GNU Screen uses 'C-a' (Control-A) as as the command character. Trouble is, this interferes with the Line Editing feature in Bash (and GNU Readline), because Control-A in Bash will Move to the start of the line."

I know I can [set the Command Character to another key sequence](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html#Command-Character), like "^Q" or "``" (Backtick), but I have trouble finding another key sequence which isn't already in use (^Q is used by the terminal, backtick is used when writing shell scripts). It appears that the Command Character may only be one or two characters in length. Can I set the GNU Screen control character to be something like "Control-Shift-A"?

(I can't use more then one hyperlink yet, so I cannot link to the Bash documentation)

Comment: For the sake of not getting disoriented when using `screen` on other systems, you might be best off to stick with the default keybindings, or at least to learn them first.  `^A a` will, by default, send the usual `^A` key combo.  It is a bit inconvenient if you use that combo a lot; I usually use the `HOME` key instead because of this.  But then that doesn't always work either.

Comment: No love here for Ctrl-space.  Works great.

Comment: So tragic that GNU Screen is so incredibly hostile to GNU Emacs by default.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The problem with <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd> is that most terminal emulation programs do not send a different code for it from the one sent by <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd>, so there would be no way for *screen* to tell the difference.

You might be able to use C-q if you do `stty -ixon` to disable “software flow control” on the tty. I usually do this so I can use C-s to search on the command line.

You might consider C-^, since it seems to be usually unbound. It is <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>6</kbd> on US keyboard layouts, but it may be difficult to type on other layouts.

Most people never use the tty control character C-\ to send SIGQUIT. To use it, disable the tty functionality with with `stty quit undef` and bind it as your prefix key. This is a bit risky though, since if you hit C-\ on a tty where the quit key has not been disabled with *stty*, you might kill the foreground process instead of activating *screen*.

I switched to [*tmux*](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/) a while ago. Its default is C-b [because it was developed under *screen* and did not interfere with *screen*'s default](http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/message.php?msg_name=20100429195120.GA17144%40yelena.nicm.ath.cx). I have found that C-b works fairly well for me (I usually use the arrow keys for single character movement on the shell command line—though I use M-b and M-f to move by words).

Incidentally, the author of *tmux* uses C-a in his primary sessions and [always types C-a twice](http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/message.php?msg_name=20100429201207.GD15766%40yelena.nicm.ath.cx) (whether in a *tmux* session or not). If you are willing to adopt this habit, it seems like a decent compromise since the second C-a should be a no-op in most Emacs-like editing contexts. It would not work so will if you often use programs/contexts outside of *screen* where the second C-a would not be a no-op.

By default, C-a C-a is bound to the *other* command (switch to most recently active screen) in *screen*. To have C-a C-a send an actual C-a and have C-a o switch windows, put the following in your `.screenrc`:

```
escape ^A^A
bind o other
```

Comment: This sounds good, then I realized that in GNU Screen, typing C-a twice will toggle to the window displayed previously. Maybe I can map "C-a C-a" to something else, although I'm not really sure how to do that (Looks like I need to specify 'escape xy' or 'meta' for this)

See http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html#Other-Window

Comment: @Stefan Lasiewski: Oops, I forgot that C-a C-a does not send C-a by default. See the addition at the end of the answer for a bit of configuration that makes C-a C-a send C-a and C-a o switch to the previous window.

Comment: Works great! C-a C-a will send an actual C-a to the underlying shell and C-a o' will switch to the 'other' window. To send 'C-a' to Bash, hit 'C-a' twice. This should be a no-op outside of screen, and shouldn't cause problems.

Answer (score 44):

No need for the workaround.
To move to the beginning of the line while using screen in bash, use

<kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd> (release and then) <kbd>A</kbd>

In general, if there's a screen control character conflicts with a bash shortcut, the bash shortcut's first <kbd>Control</kbd> will be replaced with <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd>

Likewise for other line editing shortcuts.

Comment: thanks, i did not now this, even though it's that easy. indeed no need to reconfigure anything. i like your answer best.

Comment: +1 ty - this is, by far, the best option.  Funny thing is, while trying this out, I hit C-a C-a by accident and found yet another great combo.

Answer (score 4):

I use C-\ for Screen and I can't recommend it enough.  You may hit any other key definition on accident but not generally C-\ .   That's what I like about it.

Answer (score 2):

I use this .`screenrc`

```
escape ^bb
```

Example: To detach you type `ctrl-b d`

Answer (score 0):

I use ctrl-_ (which can also be produced by ctrl+7 and usually ctrl+/) with screen/tmux.

Answer (score 0):

I use ctrl-z most of the time, but also use ctrl-x for some.  I don't use the 'stop' interrupt that much, but when it is needed, I can type ^zz.  This also allows me to start secondary screen sessions on remote servers that use the default ctrl-a.  And if I start a third session (on a third server), then I can use ctrl-x.  Ctrl-x is the lockscreen function, which in many environments is not all that usual (since screen is often running inside a terminal emulator).